# Escape custom tags except html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, html-escape-characters

I want to escape custom tags except for HTML tags such as strong, bold, italic.

```
 Input: "Hello World! <notification>Name</notification><nat>Nat tag</nat> <strong>This should be strong</strong><nas>Nas Tag</nas>"

Output: Hello World! <notification>Name</notification> <nat>Nat tag</nat>**This should be strong**<nas> Nas Tag</nas>
```

string.replace(/</g, "<").replace(/>/g, ">")
.replace(/"/g, """).replace(/'/g, "'")
.replace(/<(?!/?strong>)[^>]+>/g, '')

I tried with the above replace but it is also replacing `<strong> with &lt; strong &gt;`
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to have a whitelist of allowed tags and "escape" anything that isn't in the list. Something like this will work for a simple implementation, but in general, [regex is not a good tool for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1444609).

```js
var input = "Hello World! <notification asdfasd=asd>Name</notification><nat>Nat tag</nat> <strong>This should be strong</strong><nas>Nas Tag</nas>"

var output = escapeCustomTags(input, ['strong'])
console.log(output);

function escapeCustomTags(input, allowed_tags = []) {

  // Make allowed tags array lower case
  allowed_tags = allowed_tags.map(c => c.toLowerCase());

  // Output is the input, edited
  var output = input;

  // Attempt to match an opening or closing HTML tag
  var reg = /<\/?([a-zA_Z0-9]*)[^>]*?>/g;

  // An array that will contain all disallowed tags
  var disallowed_tags = [];

  // For each tag in the input, if it's allowed, skip
  // Else, add it to the array.
  var match;
  while ((match = reg.exec(input)) !== null) {
    if (allowed_tags.includes(match[1].toLowerCase())) continue;
    disallowed_tags.push(match[0]);
  }

  // Replace each disallowed tag with the "escaped" version
  disallowed_tags.forEach(tag => {
    var find = tag;
    var replace = tag.replace('<', '&lt;').replace('>', '&gt;');
    output = output.replace(find, replace)
  });

  return output;
}
```

Comment: the problem is I don't know how many custom tags I can have which are coming from the backend. so unable to put them in the whitelist.

Comment: You're not whitelisting the custom tags, you're HTML encoding the custom tags. A whitelist is a list of things that are *allowed*.

Comment: yes got it. I am also trying one test case like Hello World! <notification asdfasd=asd>Name</notification><nat>Nat tag</nat> <span style="font-weight:bold;">This should be strong</span><nas>Nas Tag</nas>
and giving span in allowedTags but considering span tag, not my style.